# Javascript Loops within a Loop character testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a loop that goes through a huge string of characters. Checks each digit against individual digits in another string and highlights the matches...

```
var decypher = "782137829431783498892347847823784728934782389";

var systemPass = "789544";

for (var x = 0; x < decypher.length; x++) { //loop through the array
    var switcher = 0; //not run this row yet
    for (var p = 0; p < systemPass.length; p++) { //loop through each digit in the password
        if(eval(decypher[x]) === eval(systemPass[p])) { //if the password digit matches the array digit
            if (switcher === 0) { //not run yet...
                $('body').append("<p style='color: green; float: left;'>"+decypher[x]+"</p>");
                switcher = 1; //finished running
            }
        } else { //no match
            if (switcher === 0) { //not run yet...
                $('body').append("<p style='color: silver; float: left;'>"+decypher[x]+"</p>");
                switcher = 1; //finished running
            }
        } 
    }   
}
```

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/J4wbk/12/

My question is, **how come it's only ever highlighting the `7's`?** I've been scratching my head for ages over this!

**[EDIT]**
Thanks to "@Yograj Gupta" - I've removed the `switcher` variable, but now I get multiple instances of each character: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/J4wbk/22/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you're definitely doing this the hard way.  Use `indexOf` instead (or, as Johan pointed out, `jQuery.inArray`):

http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/euGLn/1/

```
var decypher = "782137829431783498892347847823784728934782389";
var systemPass = "789544";

for (var x = 0; x < decypher.length; x++) {
    // if(systemPass.indexOf(decypher[x]) > -1) { // Thanks, Johan
    if ($.inArray(decypher[x], systemPass) > -1) {
        $('body').append("<p style='color: green; float: left;'>"+decypher[x]+"</p>");
    } else { //no match
        $('body').append("<p style='color: silver; float: left;'>"+decypher[x]+"</p>");
    } 
}
```

Although there's lots of other clean-up to recommend here, at least the loop is easier.

-- Scott

Comment: Bah, 1 min faster than me -.-

Comment: You can replace for condition with `for (var x in decypher)` and if statement with `if(~systemPass.indexOf(decypher[x]))` to further reduce the code :) http://jsfiddle.net/jax2u/

Comment: Even though we both used `indexOf` in our answer, maybe it would be better to use `$.inArray()` to make it work in ie7?

Comment: @Johan - yes, that's probably right.  I'll edit to incorporate.

Answer (score 1):

It is displaying only 7's, because you are making switcher = 1 in inner loop in very first iteration.

So when it come 7 the 7 is present on 0 index in your systemPass var, so very first iteration check it present and display it as green. but for all it go for else and display in silver and switcher becomes 1 there.

So, you should check your value against indexOf function.

Comment: Ah *I SEE!*. But now I get http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/J4wbk/19/ (multiple instances of each character...)

Answer (score 1):

Like this? Or did i miss something?

```
var decypher = "782137829431783498892347847823784728934782389".split('');

var systemPass = "789544".split('');

$.each(decypher, function(i, v){

    if(systemPass.indexOf(v) !== -1)
        $('body').append("<p style='color: green; float: left;'>"+ v +"</p>");
    else
        $('body').append("<p style='color: silver; float: left;'>"+ v +"</p>");

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J4wbk/22/

Answer (score 1):

check out this...http://jsfiddle.net/J4wbk/26/

I think this will help

Explanation:
You are assigning switcher = 1 inside the inner loop.So, after the first matching the switcher is 1 and always the else part is executed.
And you are getting multiple letters because you are appending every letter to the decypher inside the inner loop and it is added the systemPass.length times.

Answer (score 0):

I made change in your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4wbk/23/)
I updated my code now it should solve your problem

```
var decypher = "782137829431783498892347847823784728934782389";

    var pass = 789544;
    pass = "" + pass; var temp = '';
    for(var k =0; k < pass.length; k++){
      temp += pass[k] + '|';
    }
    temp = temp.substring(0, temp.length-1) ;

    console.log(new RegExp(temp,'g'));

    document.body.innerHTML =decypher.replace(new RegExp(temp,'g'), function(a){

        return '<span>'+a + '</span>';

    });

​
```

Comment: I don't think he actually wanted to replace the 7's. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2HvwT/2/

NOTE: Updated the fiddle with indexOf() as suggested by Scott Sauyet

Code:

```
for (var x = 0; x < decypher.length; x++) { //loop through the array
    var found = systemPass.indexOf(decypher[x]);
    $('body').append("<p style='color: "+(found !== -1?'green':'silver')+"; float: left;'>"+decypher[x]+"</p>");
}
```